# Change label text color with checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I'm using [angular-ui-switch](https://github.com/xpepermint/angular-ui-switch) on my page. I have on/off labels on either side of the switch. The switch works, but I need to change the color of the text when the toggle switches from on to off and vice versa. The label text should be black when the slider is on that side and blue on the other.

HTML:

```
<div class="toggle-container">
    <div class="switch-label" ng-class="{enabled:enabled.laww, disabled:!enabled.laww}">Off</div>
        <switch ng-model="enabled.laww" ng-init="enabled.laww=false" class="green unchecked">
            {{ enabled }}
        </switch>
    <div class="switch-label" ng-class="{enabled:!enabled.laww, disabled:enabled.laww}">On</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.enabled {
      color: #337ab7;
}
.disabled {
      color: #000;
}
```

I've been searching and it seems `ng-class` might be the way to go, but I'm not sure sure how that would fit into my code since I already have `class`. How should I handle this?

**Edit**

I added `ng-class="{enabled:enabled.laww}"` to both labels and that got the labels to change colors when I turn the switch on or off, but they both change to the same color at the same time. I need them to alternate colors for when it's on or off. Do I need to add another class to `ng-class`?

**Edit 2**

I figured it out! I had to add a disabled class to `ng-class` and a not true state in order for the colors to switch. Please see above code for fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by using ng-class. You can represent a class with an object-like representation:

```
<div class="{switch-label: enable.laww}">On</div>
```

Hence the class attribute will be turned on based on the value assigned to it. In this case, the value of enable.laww will be used to activate/deactivate the value of switch-label.

I'm attaching an example in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dxkM8mCkLYTMfuusm09x?p=preview

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []).
    controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.myCheckBox = true;
});
```

In the css:

```
.greenbg {
     background: lightgreen;
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheckBox">Click me
<div ng-class="{greenbg: myCheckBox}">I'm just some div</div>
```

You can find more details and examples here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Since I'm using angular-ui-switch, I think my ng-model has to stay as `enabled` unless I can combine models, which I don't think I can. Also, the `class="green unchecked"` is just to make the toggle slider green.

Comment: I'm not following you. Could you please rephrase? Providing an example in plunker would be nice, too.

Comment: I tried creating a plunker but angular-ui-switch wouldn't add to the dependency library so my code doesn't come through as it should. What I meant was, your code changes ng-model when my code already has an ng-model that depends on angular-ui-switch. I need to call the switch through ng-model=enabled.

Comment: I used my own checkbox just to show you how to handle the ng-class value, which seemed to be your question. You can use your existing ng-model to handle the ng-class value. If what I said is not what you meant, feel free to provide a clear example of exacly what you need.

Comment: I got it to work by adding ng-class to my label divs, I thought I had to add it to the existing class for the switch. Anyway, it's halfway to working as I need it to. I made edits to my question.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Thanks for your help! See edit for solution :)